# Polite way to say: As far as I'm concerned?

Tags: synonyms, paraphrasing

Is there a way we can use the phrase "as far as I'm concerned" in a polite way in an email? eg:

As far as we are concerned the task was carried out according to stated standards.

Comment: Yes - place it in an appropriate context.

Comment: What @Lawrence said. ***As far as I'm concerned,*** this question is Off Topic because it lacks context. But honestly, what difference would it make to the "politeness" of the preceding sentence whether I included those highlighted words or not?

Comment: The "legalese standard boilerplate" for contexts such as OP's is ***To the best of our knowledge [and belief]***. That's what you always see where external auditors, for example, are required to assess whether a company's trading / financial records are "valid, accurate, legal,..."

Comment: There is nothing impolite about the phrase in the first place . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for a polite way to express that you may have an opinion that is different from the reader's. In these cases, it is sometimes best to avoid "fluff" like the snippet you suggest. Your current structure begs the reader to consider whether you have done any work at all. Instead:

> The task was carried out according to ***our understanding of*** the stated standards.

In this way, there is no question of whether or not a task has been carried out. The tolerance for difference of opinion is now adjusted to more closely target the definition of work.